# Google Form Trigger Does Not Always Fire

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I have a Google Form trigger that is supposed to run a function in my response spreadsheet every time the submit button is pressed on the form. The function will send emails to specific people.

To run the function from my response spreadsheet I export my google script from my response spreadsheet as a library and import it into my google form script.

Everything works well, however the trigger doesn't always fire when the submit button is pressed on the form.

Script in spreadsheet:

```
function onReportOrApprovalSubmit() {

  var SUPERVISOR_1_APPROVAL_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1eIN7NaeVmDEFck_gPH5hA1VuAHFzkOiHOcS67fXqtlw";
  var SUPERVISOR_1_FORM_URL = "https://docs.google.com/a/londonhydro.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf_tA7g29dKR2JaB4v4F3cBqkSbdrNnHqmumoMjJFiLLdQXJQ/viewform";
  var MANAGER_APPROVAL_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1WbriYc0aCKaeSywAOw2ZDL-g7PmF_CBCrlgB522Rg7k";
  var MANAGER_FORM_URL = "https://docs.google.com/a/londonhydro.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc9Tbf-ZMQLBK56EXR3hY3oFp-y6NMa_NzWR8BByfm9_ebwpw/viewform";
  var STATE_SUPERVISOR_EMAIL = "SUPERVISOR_EMAIL";
  var STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL = "MANAGER_EMAIL";
  var STATE_APPROVED = "APPROVED";
  var STATE_DENIED = "DENIED";
  var COLUMN_STATE_SUPERVISOR = 89;
  var COLUMN_STATE_MANAGER = 90;


  // This is the injury report form spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fZq6zY-4PFhp-qExizNs0Bra0s6XAAtUJWF7QdsZTIo");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Also open the Approval Spreadsheets
  var approvalsSupervisorSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SUPERVISOR_1_APPROVAL_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var approvalsManagerSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MANAGER_APPROVAL_SPREADSHEET_ID);


  var approvalsSupervisorSheet = approvalsSupervisorSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; //get 1st sheet
  var approvalsManagerSheet = approvalsManagerSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  // Fetch all the data from the injury report form spreadsheet
  var data = getRowsData(sheet);

  // Fetch all the data from approval sheets
  var approvalsSupervisorData = getApprovalSupervisorData(approvalsSupervisorSheet);
  var approvalsManagerData = getApprovalManagerData(approvalsManagerSheet);

  // For every injury report
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var row = data[i];
    row.rowNumber = i + 2;





    if (!row.supervisorState) {
       Logger.log("no supervisor email yet");
      sendReportToSupervisor(row);
      sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE_SUPERVISOR).setValue(row.supervisorState);

    } else if (row.supervisorState == STATE_SUPERVISOR_EMAIL) {

      for (var j = 0; j < approvalsSupervisorData.length; ++j) {

        var approval = approvalsSupervisorData[j];

        if (row.rowNumber != approval.reportID) {
          Logger.log("failed expenseId: " + approval.reportID + " rowNumber: " + row.rowNumber);
          continue;
        }

        Logger.log("pass");
        // Email the employee to notify the Manager's decision about the report.
        sendSupervisorApprovalResults(row, approval);
        // Update the state of the report to APPROVED or DENIED
        sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE_SUPERVISOR).setValue(row.supervisorState);
        break;
      }//end for

    }//end else if



    if(!row.managerState && row.supervisorState != STATE_SUPERVISOR_EMAIL && row.supervisorState){

      Logger.log("no manager email yet");
      sendReportToManager(row);
      sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE_MANAGER).setValue(row.managerState);

    }//end if
    else if(row.managerState == STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL && row.supervisorState != STATE_SUPERVISOR_EMAIL && row.supervisorState){

      for (var j = 0; j < approvalsManagerData.length; ++j) {

        var approval = approvalsManagerData[j];

        if (row.rowNumber != approval.reportID) {
          Logger.log("failed expenseId: " + approval.reportID + " rowNumber: " + row.rowNumber);
          continue;
        }//end if

        Logger.log("pass");
        // Email the employee to notify the Manager's decision about the report.
        sendManagerApprovalResults(row, approval);
        // Update the state of the report to APPROVED or DENIED
        sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE_MANAGER).setValue(row.managerState);
        break;
      }//end for

    }//end else if 

  }//end for every injury report

}//end onReportOrApprovalSubmit
```

Script in my form:

```
function onSubmit() {
  EmailChain.onReportOrApprovalSubmit();
}
```

Comment: Do you get some error notification in your mailbox? While setting up the trigger, use error notification to send immediately.

Comment: I have that set up, no error notification though.

Comment: Looks like your script is long and may take significant time to finish. There are chances that your conditions failing when 2 response submitted almost immediately. Use LockService to eliminate this condition https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out.